# Javascript- onclick event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My codes are

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<div class='hide' data-id='one'>Description one</div>
<div class='hide' data-id='two'>Descripttion two</div>
<div class='hide' data-id='three'>Description Three</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.hide').click(function(){
    if($(this).data('id')=='one'){$('#main').html(myData)};
});

$('button').click(function(){alert('thank you');});

var myData = 'thank you<br/><button>previous</button>';
```

Why my button on click event i.e. alert isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#main').on('click','button',function(){alert('thank you');});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Today I learn something new.